# Where can I find how to set-up Rails as a backend for AngularJS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, api-design

I've set-up Rails with AngularJS but am now looking to implement an API between the two. All tutorials I've found on the matter are either incredibly tough to follow or overly simplistic. Do any good tutorials exist on this topic? I apologize for the broad question but am near wit's end. Any help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: try this book **Agile Web Development with Rails 4** by **Dave Thomas , Sam Ruby , David Heinemeier Hansson**. I found it helpful to learn how to design an application in Rails.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for CRUD functionality:

- Here's a nice guide to make Rails RESTful API's: [Building and documenting API in Rails](https://www.amberbit.com/blog/2014/2/19/building-and-documenting-api-in-rails/)
- And here's a simple guide to use Angular's $resource with RESTful API's:  [Creating a CRUD App in Minutes with Angular’s $resource](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/)

This way you don't even need to have angular integrated into rails project.

Comment: @Jester Jeffrey was this helpful? If it wasn't let me know and I'll delete the answer. Thanks!